# Parse HTML from a textarea using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I would like to parse some html content from a textarea and get a value from a selected tag using jquery. I tried the below code but no hope.

```js
var a = $('#a').val();
 var dom_nodes = $($.parseHTML(a));
 alert(dom_nodes.find('#ae').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="a">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
 <b:if cond='data:skin.vars.body_background.image and data:features.responsiveBackgrounds' id='ae'>
      <b:with value='&quot;body&quot;' var='selector'>
        <b:include cond='not data:view.isPreview' data='skin.vars.body_background.image' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
      </b:with>
    </b:if>
    </html>  
</textarea>
```

Comment: The error clearly indicates that you did not include the jQuery library.

Comment: You are missing jQuery library reference to the page.

Comment: even after including jquery I dont the inner html

Comment: That looks remarkably like XML, not HTML...  the `<?xml` is the first clue...

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseXML` instead.

```js
var a = $('#a').val();
var dom_nodes = $($.parseXML(a));
alert(dom_nodes.find('#ae').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="a">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
 <b:if cond='data:skin.vars.body_background.image and data:features.responsiveBackgrounds' id='ae'>
      <b:with value='&quot;body&quot;' var='selector'>
        <b:include cond='not data:view.isPreview' data='skin.vars.body_background.image' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
      </b:with>
    </b:if>
    </html>  
</textarea>
```

Comment: for this sample code..the above solution works fine...but I'm dealing with lots of code that comes under the textbox. In that case it shows none :(

Comment: and most of the tags that comes in the textarea does'nt have a end tag like xml does..

Comment: Try running it through here to see where it's messed up https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator

Comment: like I mentioned earlier, most the tags in the code does'nt have an end tag.. its self closed. So it shows invalid XML.. in that case how can I fetch data from the XML file

Comment: `$.parseXML` can definitely process self closed tags. Even in this snippet, `b:include` is self closed. Are you sure there's nothing else causing it to be invalid?

Comment: here's the fiddle... its a  long code though https://jsfiddle.net/excoafyk/ a blogger template

Comment: Probably gets confused a bunch of times going through all that thinking it's part of the page's html. I [encoded all the HTML entities](https://mothereff.in/html-entities) and put it in here and now it works. https://jsfiddle.net/r5Lpabqz/

Comment: thanks.. for elements like head html and div it works perfectly.... how can we select elements by id for elements like <b:section-contents id='sidebar-right-1'> https://jsfiddle.net/r5Lpabqz/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DomParser` to get the `ae` node.

```js
var xml = document.getElementById('a').value;
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
var ae = xmlDoc.getElementById('ae');
console.log(ae.id);
```

```html
<textarea id="a">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
 <b:if cond='data:skin.vars.body_background.image and data:features.responsiveBackgrounds' id='ae'>
      <b:with value='&quot;body&quot;' var='selector'>
        <b:include cond='not data:view.isPreview' data='skin.vars.body_background.image' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
      </b:with>
    </b:if>
    </html>  
</textarea>
```